# Update in Lookup Activity, in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am using the below flow.

```
 ODATA -> Blob storage (JSON)
 JSON -> Snowflake table
 Copy Data -> Copy Data - Lookup
```

Both copy data is working fine.

In the lookup (query), i have given. (Need to add 1 value in table, its a variant column)

```
Update T1 set source_json = object_insert(source_json,device_type,web_browser,TRUE);)
```

When i use the above query in snowflake database it works fine, the table has 25K rows.

When run from pipeline, it gives the below error.

Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the workarounds are provided below.

Execute multiple SQL files using SnowSql (command line utility) as described below:

```
snowsql -c cc -f file1.sql -f file2.sql -f file3.sql
```

Once we have downloaded and installed the snowsql tool, we can wrap up all our SQL queries in a single .sql file and call that file using bash.

For example, suppose that we have written all the queries which we would like to run around in a file named `abc.sql` stored in /tmp.

We can then run the following command:

```
snowsql -a enter_accountname -u enter_your_username -f /tmp/abc.sql
```

For reference:

[Workaround for multiple sql statement in a single api call are not supported](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000074VumOSAS/is-there-a-workaround-for-multiple-sql-statements-in-a-single-api-call-are-not-supported)

[Multiple single api call are not supported use one api call per statement instead](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007ltRE7/multiple-sql-statements-in-a-single-api-call-are-not-supported-use-one-api-call-per-statement-instead)

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKhandave-MT where does snowsql get installed to and where does it execute from in an Azure Data Factory context? eg does this solution require Azure Batch? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Requirement got changed.
Our flow
Lookup1 -> Copy data -> Copy data > Lookup2
We passed the values from the lookup1 and ran the stored procedure.